# finding unique values from two arrays of objects based on two keys i.e from and to in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have two arrays of objects like shown below :

```
    var b = [{"from":2,"to":7,"id":1},{"from":3,"to":9,"id":2},{"from":2,"to":7,"id":3}]
    var c = [{"from":3,"to":9,"id":2,"style":""},{"from":2,"to":7,"id":3,"style":"dash-line"},{"from":4,"to":2,"id":4,"style":"dash-line"},{"from":2,"to":4,"id":5,"style":""},{"from":4,"to":2,"id":6,"style":"dash-line"}];
```

what i want is an array of objects from above two , which has unique "from" ,"to" and "style" should be either ""(blank) or undefined.With unique ids.

i.e

```
    output = [{"from":2,"to":7,"id":0},{"from":3,"to":9,"id":1},{"from":2,"to":4,"id":6,"style":""}]
```

am able to get it as shown in below code, but i feel code can be optimized or there can be a better way to do it. Please help....Thanks.

```
  var b = [{"from":2,"to":7,"id":1},{"from":3,"to":9,"id":2},{"from":2,"to":7,"id":3}]
    var c = [{"from":3,"to":9,"id":2,"style":""},{"from":2,"to":7,"id":3,"style":"dash-line"},{"from":4,"to":2,"id":4,"style":"dash-line"},{"from":2,"to":4,"id":5,"style":""},{"from":4,"to":2,"id":6,"style":"dash-line"}];
    var a = b.concat(c);
findUniQue(a);

function findUniQue(a){
    var tempArr =[];
    for(var i =0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i].style == undefined || a[i].style != 'dash-line' ){
            var count = 0;
            if(tempArr.length>0){
             for(var j =0;j<tempArr.length;j++){
                if((a[i].from == tempArr[j].from)&&(a[i].to == tempArr[j].to)){
                    count--;
                    break;  
                }
                else{
                    count++;
                }
                if(count == tempArr.length){
                    a[i].id = i;
                    tempArr.push(a[i]);
                }
                }
             }
             else{
                a[i].id = i;
                tempArr.push(a[i]);
             }
        }
    }
    console.dir(tempArr);
}
```

Comment: If your code works in general it might be better fitting for code review.

Comment: @Nit yah you check above code snippet in console , it gives desired  result but what am looking for is a better approach to do it as when data will increase , cross looping which i did can cause performance issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeduplicate(){
    var array = [{id:5},{id:8},{id:9},{id:10},{id:5},{id:8}];
    var size = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[j].id !== array[i].id)
                continue;
            array.splice(j,1);
            j--;
            size--;
        } // for j
    } // for i
    console.log(array);
}
```